# Data set from cameras in Gazebo

Tags: ros2, gazebo-simu

I'm trying to create a data set using images from the front camera of a drone simulation in Gazebo. I want to also have bounding box for the models in the simulation.
My  problem is that i don't know how to use ROS2 topics in order to get the right bounding box for each model and to save images with them in it.

If anyone can tell me maybe some steps to do this I will be grateful!

This is the drone simulation that I'm using: [sjtu_drone](https://github.com/NovoG93/sjtu_drone)

I tried to make 2 nodes, one for saving images from simulation and one for getting data about the objects state. My second node won't work.

[The package with the 2 nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OZr2.png)

Since the website won't let me paste all my code here because of an error i will give a link for a text file with all of my code for the the nodes and "objectstate.msg".

[Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mEhbdkVS-fdqRzcUAKDsERWvKfXFkt-F/view?usp=sharing)